# Can I see the hooks in a repository I don't own?

Tags: api, github

I want to know if a Github repository has defined a certain service hook (Webhook URL) but I am not the owner of the repos (though I am a collaborator).

Is there a way to do that via the API (or any other programmatic way)?

If it helps, the repository in question may sometimes belong to an individual and sometimes to an organization.

Comment: The `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/hooks` mentioned in http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#json-http don't work?

Comment: No. I'm not the owner of the repos so it doesn't.

Comment: But that is not what it means: `:owner` is just to be replaced by the name of the owner of the repo, and `:repo` by the name of the repo.

Comment: I understand that. It does not work. If I authenticate as the owner of the repo, it does work.

Comment: Note: you now (February 2014) can access hooks of a repo you don't own. see [my updated answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20748006/6309).

Answer (score 1):

I confirm the [OP's conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20732958/can-i-see-the-hooks-in-a-repository-i-dont-own?noredirect=1#comment31088771_20732958):

> It does not work. If I authenticate as the owner of the repo, it does work.

That means the [List query](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#json-http) (`GET /repos/:owner/:repo/hooks`) won't work if you are not owner (or admin for an organization) of a repo.

The [Hooks GitHub API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks) does mention:

> The Repository Hooks API allows repository admins to manage the post-receive hooks for a repository.

---

**Update February 2014**: "[**New scopes for managing repository hooks**](http://developer.github.com/changes/2014-02-10-repo-hook-scopes/)"

You now can see hooks for a repo you don't own, provided the owner set the right scope:

> Many third party services need to set up **[hooks](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/)** in order to act upon events in your repositories.
>   We’ve introduced three new **[scopes](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)** that **provide more granular access to your repository hooks without allowing access to your repository contents**:

- **`read:repo_hook`** grants read access to hooks in public or private repositories.
- **`write:repo_hook`** grants read and write access to hooks in public or private repositories.
- **`admin:repo_hook`** grants read, write, and delete access to hooks in public or private repositories.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need to be a repository admin, just need to have push permission. But I'd like to be able to confirm that the hook exists, because if it doesn't, my app is not going to function properly. I guess I am out of luck unless I ask people to add me to their orgs as an admin, which gives me more power than I need or want.

Comment: @DanTenenbaum it would be useful to check and ask to github support if there is any other way to access those hooks.